# Error while building R package on Travis CI" "tlmgr update --self" failed

Tags: r, latex, travis-ci, tex

I was building an R package on https://travis-ci.org/ and got an error:

```
    The command "tlmgr update --self" failed and exited with 25 during .
```

The last lines of Travis CI output:

[image]

When I call `devtools::check()` locally on Windows 10 in RStudio no errors nor warnings arise.

I found that `tlmgr` concerns with LaTeX/TexLive packages, and In Travis CI documentation ["Building an R Project"](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r#LaTeX-TexLive-Packages) it's written that some LaTeX/TexLive may be need to be installed if vignettes require. (Note: there are no vignettes in my package yet.)

Configuration in `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: R
sudo: false
cache: packages
r_github_packages:
  - jimhester/covr
after_success:
  - Rscript -e 'covr::codecov()'
```

My **question:** what is the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I've posted an issue at
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6139

Comment: Yep, I also just had the same problem.

Comment: me 3 - thanks for posting this

Comment: The problem's been fixed: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/pull/743, now we just need to wait until the pull request is accepted.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Glad to hear a fix is on the way! So grateful for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tlmgr can't accessing the current repository, you can rollback the repository to the archived version with:

```
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final
```

which gaves

```
tlmgr: setting default package repository to ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final
```

Source: [A little trick with tlmgr: Unknown directive …containerchecksum error](https://darrengoossens.wordpress.com/2016/06/20/a-little-trick-with-tlmgr-unknown-directive-containerchecksum-error/)